# How to fetch json and display img in flatlist (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a small react native app which can fetch json and display gifs in flatlist.

But it is not working and i don't know where is the problem!

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=1FS646G91JAT&q=meme&limit=50')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const array_URL = []

        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          array_URL.push(
            {
              id: i + 1,
              url: json.results[i].media[0]["mediumgif"].url
            }
          )
        }

        setData(array_URL)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.url }}
            />
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where the problem is?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo.

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/belligerent-celery

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  useWindowDimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.tenor.com/v1/random?key=1FS646G91JAT&q=meme&limit=10')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const array_URL = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          array_URL.push({
            id: i + 1,
            url: json.results[i].media[0]['mediumgif'].url,
          });
        }

        setData(array_URL);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          extraData={data}
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Image
              resizeMode="cover"
              style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 200 }}
              source={{ uri: item.url }}
            />
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! So I would like to know that the missing thing in my code is "style" in <Image/>?